# Sailsjs: Cannot use pug as view engine?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, pug, pugjs

I'm using sails.js and want to use pug (formerly jade) as view engine but when i changed engine in the views.js, i got an error.

```
error: Invalid view engine (pug)-- are you sure it supports `consolidate`?
```

I already installed pug via npm and installed newest [consolidates](https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js)

This is part of my views.js file:

```
  engine: 'pug',
```

And this is my package.json:

```
    "pug": "^2.0.0-alpha6",
```

Answer (score 0):

Sails core just [updated its version of Consolidate recently](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/commit/a70623ce2809d497b3581268354f06904d862268) because of this very issue, so it'll published with the next patch release (v0.12.4).  In the meantime, you can use the master branch (`npm install github://balderdashy/sails`), or you can try this in your `config/views.js`:

```
engine: {
  name: 'jade',
  module: 'pug',
  ext: 'pug'
}
```